# How To Solve This No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I know, there are lots of question about this topic and I have tried each and every Posts. But, I couldn't able to solve this error. That's why I posted this question.

I am creating a website where I have used a web service called holidaywebservice. I have used Jquery and Ajax to request and get a response from the server. When I input data and click search button to get response, Console Tab of the web browser shows me this error -

> Failed to load http://holidaywebservice.com/Holiday...ce2.asmx?WSDL:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

How can Fix this error without using any extension ??

Here is the code.

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Country : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="UnitedStates" id="country">
                    <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Year : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" value="2018"
                                  id="year"> <br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                    Month : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="month" value="04"
                                   id="month"> <br>
                </div>

                <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search</a>

                <p id="errorModal"></p> <br>

                <div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix"></div>

            </form>
            </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->

             <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-left" id="tblData">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>Country</td>
                        <td>HolidayCode</td>
                        <td>Descriptor</td>
                        <td>BankHoliday</td>
                        <td>Date</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tbody id="tblBody"></tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function (e) {
                        var country = $('#country').val();
                        var year = $('#year').val();
                        var month = $('#month').val();

                        //console.log(departureDate);

                        var str = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>' +
                            '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">' +
                            '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                            '<ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                            '<ns1:countryCode>' + country + '</ns1:countryCode>' +
                            '<ns1:year>' + year + ' </ns1:year>' +
                            '<ns1:month>' + month + '</ns1:month>' +
                            '</ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                            '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                            '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

                        //console.log(departureDate);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL',
                            method: 'POST',
                            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                            data: str,
                            dataType: "text",
                            crossDomain: true,
                            //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);

                                document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=data;

                                var xml = data,
                                  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
                                  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),

                                  $CountryXML = $xml.find( "Country" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                  $( "#Country" ).append( $CountryXML );
                                  //document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = $y.nodeValue; 

                                  //$HolidayCode = $xml.find( "HolidayCode" );
                                  //$( "#HolidayCode" ).append( $HolidayCode.text() );

                                  $HolidayCodeXML = $xml.find( "HolidayCode" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                  $( "#HolidayCode" ).append( $HolidayCodeXML );

                                  $DescriptorXML = $xml.find( "Descriptor" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                  $( "#Descriptor" ).append( $DescriptorXML );

                                  $BankHolidayXML = $xml.find( "BankHoliday" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                  $( "#BankHoliday" ).append( $BankHolidayXML );

                                  $DateXML = $xml.find( "Date" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                  $( "#Date" ).append( $DateXML );

                                  var BookBtn = '<input type="submit" value="Book" name="book" class="btn btn-primary">';

                                  $('#tblData').empty();

                                    for (var v = 0; v <= 999; v++) {
                                    var row = $('<tr><td>' + $xml.find( "Country" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                        + $xml.find( "HolidayCode" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                        + $xml.find( "Descriptor" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                        + $xml.find( "BankHoliday" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                        + $xml.find( "Date" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                        + BookBtn + '</td></tr>');
                                    $('#tblData').append(row);
                                    }

                            }

                        }); //Ajax

                        //Test function
                        //createTableAndContent(soap)

                    }); //Button

                });

</body>
</html>
```